Homebrew weapon that can target multiple creatures with a single attack roll: How strong is this?
Loosely inspired by monster attack descriptions which redundantly specify "one target," I'm trying to design an attack (for a PC) that can target multiple creatures with a single roll.
I'm okay with this ability being powerful, but I don't want it to let the user double-dip on on-hit effects, like sneak attack, smite, and most battlemaster maneuvers.
I've designed it here as a modifier for a magic weapon, but in practice it's more likely to see play as a natural weapon granted for plot reasons. I don't think that meaningfully changes the balance of it, but if I'm wrong, let me know:

Attacks with this weapon target up to 3 creatures within 5 feet of you. Use the same roll against all targets. If you have advantage and/or disadvantage against any target, roll a second die to serve as the advantage/disadvantage value against all applicable targets. Each target hit takes 1d4 + your Strength modifier bludgeoning damage. All on-hit effects other than the base damage only affect one target of your choice that was hit; you make this choice after knowing which targets are hit.

As phrased here, are there any OP combos with this ability I should be aware of? I'm aware that abilities that modify the to-hit roll (e.g. the Precise Attack maneuver) would apply against all targets, but the damage is low enough that I'm okay with that.

For clarity, Why would you rather a attack roll over a saving throw? make it more like the blade ward spell but costing an attack instead of an action?

*Sword burst, not blade ward

What level is the PC going to be?

Can this be affected by extra attack, or does it work once per turn?

It is not clear if when one of the 3 targets had adv/disadv this affects the attack roll for also the other two.

Do you decide which creature takes the on-hit effects before, or after rolling? If it's after, there's an obvious major advantage to getting a much higher chance of triggering them.

Is this just something people can do or an option they would choose? What is it competing with?

@JonAristotle I'd prefer this to be an attack for action economy reasons. Also, an attack roll targets AC, while a saving throw targets a save; they're not interchangeable.

@Eddymage Thanks. Clarified that adv/disadv is still per-target.

@Erik The intention is to decide after rolling, since that's when you decide to apply these abilities (e.g. battlemaster maneuvers). If that's OP, please leave an answer explaining how!

@SeriousBri Assume that this is an ability of a magic weapon, so it's only competing with other uses of attacks, such as attacking with other weapons, shoving, etc.

@enkryptor As written, this would work with Extra Attack. If that would push it into OP territory, that could be worth writing an answer. PC level TBD

Is there a reason why you don't want three attack rolls? You say that both on-hit effects and (dis)advantage should be per target, so it seems like you want the mechanics of three separate attacks.

Not an item strength, so not an answer, but aren't you afraid it'll be cumbersome? With advantage and disadvantage varying per target you will have less rolls, but more "which dice is which". Especially when one of the target requires only one dice and player might lose track which one is which. What are you trying to solve by introducing this mechanic?

@JoakimM.H. making one attack roll is actually important for balance. Otherwise it becomes really strong for once per turn effects like sneak attack since you get so many chances to hit.

@Mołot One reason to prefer only rolling at most 2 dice is that that's the default when playing in some VTTs, such as Roll20. In person I agree that that could be cumbersome--but when rolling two attack rolls against separate targets, you still need to specify "which die is which," so it's not any worse

This is a bit stronger than a mundane weapon, but probably only as much as an uncommon magic item
One of the primary balance concerns that you try to address is on-hot effects, and you accomplish this as far as I can tell. Firstly, effects that trigger per attack will only trigger once as you describe. Secondly, for once per turn effects, you don't get more attempts to fish for a high result since you make one attack roll for all 3 targets.
Since this is handled well from a balance perspective, let's look at the raw damage of the weapon. You deal 1d4 + Strength to each target. Here is a table showing the average damage values of this weapon as well as some other popular options:



Weapon
1 Target
2 Targets
3 Targets




Homebrew Cleaver
7.5
15
22.5


Halberd
10.5
N/A
N/A


Greatsword
12
N/A
N/A


Longsword
9.5
N/A
N/A



As you can see, as long as you  have 2 targets, this weapon outpaces the other mundane options because you are adding your Strength modifier against each target. With this in mind, I'd probably estimate this as an uncommon magic item in terms of power level. Here's a comparison to a rare magic item, a flame tongue, where it doesn't quite keep up unless you can consistently find 3 targets to attack:



Weapon
1 Target
2 Targets
3 Targets




Homebrew Cleaver
7.5
15
22.5


Flame Tongue Greatsword
19
N/A
N/A


Flame Tongue Longsword
16.5
N/A
N/A



For an uncommon item that deals comparable damage, look no further than a circlet of blasting which casts scorching ray. This deals 7 damage to up to 3 targets. The circlet of blasting is a bit more useful than your homebrew cleaver since it's ranged and can focus it's damage on one target if desired, but also has limited charges (1 per day) and a weaker attack bonus. These are approximate tradeoffs lending more credence to an uncommon rarity.

I agree with the maths, but DND rewards killing enemies more than just damaging them, so I can't see any real situations where you would prefer small damage to multiple targets. Even against 3 targets where it would do more damage I would prefer to use flame tongue and actually try to kill something (especially with extra attack etc).

@SeriousBri Even more evidence why this shouldn't be a rare item like a flame tounge

wouldn't it also be a fair comparison to check this weapon against an area-attack with 4 (a square) or 5 (a plus-shape) squares of effect? most often, those don't have targets in every square, so 1-3 seems to match up somewhat in affected creatures. Though I do believe most of those area-attacks are spells.

@Trish good point. Looking at spells helped me find another valuable comparison, a circlet of blasting
